# Is there a secure way to send variables from php to flash

Tags: php, flash, security

I am first going to start off by saying that I am relatively new to both flash and php.

Currently I have a site setup with a user login and password(in php). Upon a successful login--(php query to mysql) the user logs in and the user name and a few other variables are stored as session variables.

What I am trying to do is create an online quiz in flash. The quiz will be embedded in the web page. It required to get the users name from the session variable and pass it to flash in order to know what account is using the quiz. Is it possible to pass the users name to the flash program securely? If so where should I look for more information?

Thanks

Comment: Flash is no way secure, actually anything browser based can be hacked, not to mention using wireshark too capture the communication between flash and your server. Plus any HTTP request can be forged.

Answer (score 2):

Flash includes support for a thing called [Action Message Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) (AMF), which is a protocol that Flash applications can use to call methods on a server and receive responses.

AMF is a binary protocol, with server-side support in a variety of languages including PHP (and a number of PHP frameworks).  I suspect that if your Flash application can make HTTPS requests, it should be able to make AMF requests via HTTPS.

But ... "secure"?

If AMF data can be sniffed on the wire, it can be deserialized, just like plaintext.  Flash plugin is a closed source application, so you can't review the source then compile it yourself to be sure it's not doing anything you haven't authorized.

How do *you* define "secure"?  What exactly is the kind of attack or information leak that you're hoping to protect against?

For your application, perhaps a strategy would be to have the browser authenticate the user and establish a PHP session.  Then pass the session cookie value to the Flash application as a variable when you load it.  Then your Flash application can craft its own HTTP/HTTPS request that includes the cookie header, thus identifying the request as part of the already-established session.

It seems to me there should be a simpler way to handle this, but my knowledge of Flash is also limited.

I second the comment that you should consider not using Flash for this endeavour.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it went unnoticed: what kind of attack are you trying to prevent, how much are you ready to pay for it?

In reverse order; in order to have your server serve pages via HTTPS you need to purchase a certificate from some authorized body. This is not a free service + it expires. Serving pages using encrypted connection taxes your server by time and memory it is required to encode the data + the traffic (almost double the base size). It also makes embedding other people's content such as ads, images from other sites problematic to serve because not all ads providers will have ads served via both secure and insecure connection. This may be potentially a showstoper if you plan for your site to profit from displaying ads.

Kinds of attack: who are you protecting against whom? Are you afraid that Flash will somehow help expose your application logic to the potential attacker so that she will be able to exploit your system weak spots? For example, this could be possible if you use Flash to uploads things to your server, or allow, under some circumstances, to load server's code using it.

Or are you trying to protect users against another users, as in if one user can eavesdrop on the stuff sent by another user, it may potentially profit her?

There are also degrees and combinations of the above two.

Why do you need to pass user's name back to them? I would imagine they must already know it. Or did you by chance meant Flash should send the user name? In this case, again, what exactly is the danger? Is it the other users knowing what name is sent or the users themselves being able to send a "wrong" name? By "wrong" I mean several things at once: wrong - may be a name of another user, or, the name of the "proper" user, but sent in a way it would start another session rather than inside the already existing session (log in from another tab / browser).

Some additional info: while it is true that you would have to pay for the certificate, there's an advantage of using Flash over relying on bare browser's abilities. If your primary concern about security is less so to impress the prospects by having your entire site served over HTTPS, you could customary implement HTTPS in Flash, however, this requires a lot of work and understanding of the matter. SSL (the encryption used to serve pages over HTTPS) relies on the principle of bidirectional encoding using 2-part keys, such as, for example, RSA. The idea is that given a public key it is only possible to encrypt the data, but you need the private key to decrypt it. So it is safe to send your user the public key, which they can later use to encrypt the data they send. In such case it would be virtually impossible for anyone else to eavesdrop on the data being sent between your server and the user in the direction from user to server, and even though they might have the public key, they cant decrypt the data. But this will not prevent them from potentially knowing what information server sends to client - you should treat this as potentially always known and impossible to hide.

Comment: I am less worried about people cheating on the quiz and more or less worried about whether implementing this quiz in flash would make it more possible for someone to change the results stored in my DB.

Comment: Dane, The way I see it the direction is only flash fetching data from a php page, that in turn fetched it from the database. The user should not interact with any php or mysql page and the only direction of data transfer should be that one (mysql -> php -> flash).

Since the user had no access to the database at any point (the database is invariant to the user) , it's perfectly secure.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to make such quiz secure'ish would be:

- Flash application, at the end of quiz, sends all the answers *(not the result, just the answers)* to the PHP side *(flash can perform XHR)*
- PHP side of things can verify the users session *(if he started the quiz, if he spent more then 1 second on the quiz .. such details)*
- PHP script sends back the response to the Flash-thing with the results or an error code

Answer (score 0):

There are **ways** to send data "from PHP" to Flash, but there are no **secure ways** to do it.

To "send" any data to Flash, you'll need either...

- Print it on the same page as the Flash element (or right into the element displaying it). However, people can edit any information you print to them, and use it to manipulate the data sent to Flash.
- Have Flash make a HTTP(S) request, and take the data from there. This won't work either, since Flash documents can be decompiled, or the data can be intercepted (and even spoofed).